# android - onKeyDown mFlags variable

Tags: android, flags, onkeydown

I have a log that came back from onKeyDown event and the flag resulted in the number 520. How do I find out what the flag is? I assume its 520 = 512 + 8 = FLAG_TRACKING + FLAG_FROM_SYSTEM

I need to know for sure and I hear it has something to do with hex code. How to I convert and find out?

FROM LOG:

onKeyUp - keycode: 118 | info: KeyEvent{action=ACTION_UP code=118 repeat=0 meta=0 scancode=766 mFlags=520}

I need to know what the mFlags names are.

Thank you.

Comment: modified  my answer. only ifs.. no elses..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this to check

```
if (mFlags & FLAG_TRACKING == FLAG_TRACKING)
     // it contains FLAG_TRACKING
if (mFlags & FLAG_FROM_SYSTEM == FLAG_FROM_SYSTEM)
     // its contains FLAG_FROM_SYSTEM flag.
if ... etc...
```

Comment: it can be a combination of flags thought. In particular 520 is a combination of two. so it will fall through all of these methods for 520 and report nothing.

Comment: The control will enter a `if` block only if contains that particular flag. So in each `if` u can append the flags to a string and log all the discrete flag values. And I think that answers your question. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the full code:

```
Log.i("==BCR==", "onKeyDown - keycode: " + keyCode + " | isCanceled: " + event.isCanceled() + " | info: "  + event.toString());

        if ((event.getFlags() & KeyEvent.FLAG_FROM_SYSTEM) == KeyEvent.FLAG_FROM_SYSTEM)
        {

            Log.i("==BCR==", "onKeyDown - keycode: " + keyCode + " | FLAG: FLAG_FROM_SYSTEM");

        }else {}

        if ((event.getFlags() & KeyEvent.FLAG_TRACKING) == KeyEvent.FLAG_TRACKING)
        {

            Log.i("==BCR==", "onKeyDown - keycode: " + keyCode + " | FLAG: FLAG_TRACKING");
        }else {}



        ///FLAG_WOKE_HERE
        if ((event.getFlags() & KeyEvent.FLAG_WOKE_HERE) == KeyEvent.FLAG_WOKE_HERE)
        {

            Log.i("==BCR==", "onKeyDown - keycode: " + keyCode + " | FLAG: FLAG_WOKE_HERE");
        }else {}


        //FLAG_SOFT_KEYBOARD
        if ((event.getFlags() & KeyEvent.FLAG_SOFT_KEYBOARD) == KeyEvent.FLAG_SOFT_KEYBOARD)
        {

            Log.i("==BCR==", "onKeyDown - keycode: " + keyCode + " | FLAG: FLAG_SOFT_KEYBOARD");
        }else {}

        //FLAG_KEEP_TOUCH_MODE
        if ((event.getFlags() & KeyEvent.FLAG_KEEP_TOUCH_MODE) == KeyEvent.FLAG_KEEP_TOUCH_MODE)
        {

            Log.i("==BCR==", "onKeyDown - keycode: " + keyCode + " | FLAG: FLAG_KEEP_TOUCH_MODE");
        }else {}


        //FLAG_EDITOR_ACTION
        if ((event.getFlags() & KeyEvent.FLAG_EDITOR_ACTION) == KeyEvent.FLAG_EDITOR_ACTION)
        {

            Log.i("==BCR==", "onKeyDown - keycode: " + keyCode + " | FLAG: FLAG_EDITOR_ACTION");
        }else {}


        //FLAG_CANCELED
        if ((event.getFlags() & KeyEvent.FLAG_CANCELED) == KeyEvent.FLAG_CANCELED)
        {

            Log.i("==BCR==", "onKeyDown - keycode: " + keyCode + " | FLAG: FLAG_CANCELED");
        }else {}


        //FLAG_VIRTUAL_HARD_KEY
        if ((event.getFlags() & KeyEvent.FLAG_VIRTUAL_HARD_KEY) == KeyEvent.FLAG_VIRTUAL_HARD_KEY)
        {

            Log.i("==BCR==", "onKeyDown - keycode: " + keyCode + " | FLAG: FLAG_VIRTUAL_HARD_KEY");
        }else {}

        //FLAG_LONG_PRESS
        if ((event.getFlags() & KeyEvent.FLAG_LONG_PRESS) == KeyEvent.FLAG_LONG_PRESS)
        {

            Log.i("==BCR==", "onKeyDown - keycode: " + keyCode + " | FLAG: FLAG_LONG_PRESS");
        }else {}

        //FLAG_CANCELED_LONG_PRESS
        if ((event.getFlags() & KeyEvent.FLAG_CANCELED_LONG_PRESS) == KeyEvent.FLAG_CANCELED_LONG_PRESS)
        {

            Log.i("==BCR==", "onKeyDown - keycode: " + keyCode + " | FLAG: FLAG_CANCELED_LONG_PRESS");
        }else {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply print the constant values when a key down event occurs.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_NUMPAD_DOT

Comment: Because there are only a number of flags, the rest is their combination. The KEY_ is not a flag Its a keycode.